# PyQt5 QWebView not rendering matplotlib svg properly

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, pyqt, qwebview

I'm trying to use `QWebView` to display an html page containing several `matplotlib` generated svg files. The content displays as I would expect, however the svg figures are missing certain parts. It seems as though any purely horizontal or vertical lines aren't rendered (elements drawn with `axvline`/`axhline`, `grid`, `errorbar` etc.). Strangely, resizing the window sometimes causes the missing elements to pop into view.

What could be happening here?

**Example code**

```
from io import BytesIO
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebKitWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np

# Generate figure
fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, step=0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.grid(which='major')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.axhline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')
ax.axvline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')

# Save svg
svg = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(svg, format='svg')

# Display in gui
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
win.setWindowTitle('Test SVG rendering')
webview = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView()
webview.setContent(svg.getvalue())
layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(win)
layout.addWidget(canvas)
layout.addWidget(webview)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Output**

[image]

**After resizing window**

[image]

Comment: QtWebKit is old and unmaintained - I suggest you test with QtWebEngine instead, or with [the unmaintained newer QtWebKit](https://github.com/annulen/webkit)

Comment: I'm aware that `QtWebKit` has been deprecated. Unfortunately `QtWebEngine` isn't available on the Windows build I use because the Chromium project on which `QtWebEngine` is based doesn't support MinGW, so I don't really have a choice. I'll check out the newer `QtWebKit` you linked.

Comment: I believe the problem is caused by [this bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92254) related to clip paths. I manually edited the svg file and now it displays correctly. Hopefully it's fixed in the newer version